# How to rename file (e.g. insert characters) name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a samsung phone (note 4) that saves photos in following date format 20150401_070344

That is, yyyymmdd_hhmmss

I have 1000s of these files and would like to change them all to the following format:

2015-04-01 07.03.44 Wed

How can I do this using powershell please?

Regards

George

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, but remember here is not a 'code self service'. Do some effort to solve your needs and post the code you have tried, and maybe, someone will give you support.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get-ChildItem to retrieve the photos, iterate over it, parse the date and transform it using the script below and finally rename the file using Rename-Item cmdlet.

```
$photoDatetime = [datetime]::ParseExact("20150401_070344", "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", $null)
$formatedPhotoDateTime = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss ddd}" -f [datetime]$photoDatetime
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Jisaak's approach, but his code doesn't actually parse the date and time from the current file.

**Walkthrough**

Here is how you should do this GG,

First, be sure we're looking at the directory which has our files in it

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads' | select -first 20
>    Directory: C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       12/17/2014   9:25 AM        1151985 2014-11-18 13.53.56.jpg
-a----        12/9/2014  11:35 AM         149247 2014-12-09 16.35.58.png
-a----        12/9/2014   9:20 PM        3046709 2014-12-09 21.20.23.jpg
-a----       12/10/2014   6:33 PM        2496437 2014-12-10 18.33.13.jpg
-a----       12/10/2014   6:33 PM        2889022 2014-12-10 18.33.15.jpg
-a----       12/10/2014   6:33 PM        2298856 2014-12-10 18.33.18.jpg
-a----       12/10/2014   6:33 PM        2290490 2014-12-10 18.33.25.jpg
-a----       12/10/2014   6:33 PM        3079367 2014-12-10 18.33.34.jpg
...
```

Ok, to implement Jissak's approach, we pipe this into a ForEach object loop, and make a few tweaks to his code, like this, to see what the new name would be for each file:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads' |select -first 20 |
  ForEach-Object {
   $photoDatetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", $null)
   $formatedPhotoDateTime = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss ddd}" -f [datetime]$photoDatetime
   Write-Output "New file name would be $formatedPhotoDateTime"
}
>New filename would be 2014-53-18 01.53.56 Tue
New filename would be 2014-35-09 04.35.58 Tue
New filename would be 2014-20-09 09.20.23 Tue
New filename would be 2014-33-10 06.33.13 Wed
New filename would be 2014-33-10 06.33.15 Wed
New filename would be 2014-33-10 06.33.18 Wed
New filename would be 2014-33-10 06.33.25 Wed
New filename would be 2014-33-10 06.33.34 Wed
New filename would be 2014-56-10 06.56.02 Wed
...
```

If you like the new filename, you can now Rename each file.  Just change the last line from Write-Output to this

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$formatedPhotoDateTime$($_.Extension)" -WhatIf
>What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\2014-11-18 13.53.56
.jpg Destination: C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\2014-53-18 01.53.56 Tue.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\2014-12-09 16.35.58
.png Destination: C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads\2014-35-09 04.35.58 Tue.png".
```

If you're comfortable with the new name, simply remove the -Whatif and also remove Select -First 20 from the pipeline and run it one last time.

**Completed Script**

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\Stephen\Dropbox\Camera Uploads' | ForEach-Object {
  $photoDatetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", $null)
  $formatedPhotoDateTime = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss ddd}" -f [datetime]$photoDatetime
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$formatedPhotoDateTime$($_.Extension)" -PassThru
}
```

Comment: FoxDeploy, sorry for the super late reply, but thank you so much for the detailed answer.  I will give this a go and post back some feedback.

Comment: Foxxxxxxy! Your script - along with jisaak's contribution - worked like a charm.

Comment: Get-ChildItem |
ForEach-Object {
$photoDatetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", $null)
$formatedPhotoDateTime = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss ddd}" -f [datetime]$photoDatetime
Write-Output "Original file name would be $photoDatetime"
Write-Output "New file name would be $formatedPhotoDateTime" 
Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$formatedPhotoDateTime$($_.Extension)" -PassThru}

Comment: Awesome! Please vote up anything that helped and mark the one you feel most appropriate as the answer!